# gtk.ListStore / gtk.TreeModel and dict type

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I've a dictionary (dict type) which I would store in a `gtk.ListStore`.

Is there a way to do this ? (Which column type is good for that ?) or do I have to add as many columns in the `gtk.ListStore` as there are elements in the dictionary?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to look at the `DictionaryGrid` [quickly widget](https://launchpad.net/quidgets). See [here](http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/tutorials/all/diy-media-player-with-pygtk/) for it's usage.

The DictionaryGrid might exactly do what you need or you can copy parts of it.

Comment: It seems that there is no alternative than to add as many columns in the gtk.ListStore as there are elements in the dictionary (Apparently, the `DictionaryGrid` quickly widget does this dynamically).